# How I can set react-particles-js as background while working on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-particles-js

I am working on a portfolio with React.js and I have used react-particles-js for my background but it works as a component.
I want this component as a background.
Is there any other alternative of react-particles-js?

**This is my Home.js**

```
import Particle from "../Particle";
import Pro from '../../Assets/Pro.svg'
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

function Home() {
    return (
        <section>
            <Container fluid className='home-section'>
                <Particle />
                <Container className='home-content'>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={5} >
                            <img src={Pro} alt="home pic" className="img-fluid" />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </Container>
        </section>
    );
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the particles as a background using just options. No extra CSS needed.

You can see the `fullScreen` options here: https://particles.js.org/docs/interfaces/Options_Interfaces_FullScreen_IFullScreen.IFullScreen.html

So, the only thing you need is just add this to your particles config:

```js
{
  fullScreen: {
    enable: true,
    zIndex: 0 // or any value is good for you, if you use -1 set `interactivity.detectsOn` to `"window"` if you need mouse interactions
  },
  /* your config */
}
```

You can see a working sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tsparticles-dw43f?file=/src/App.js:190-230

It uses `react-tsparticles` but it's the same of `react-particles-js@3`. If you are not using any of these, the settings above won't work.